# I couldn't input the character value in c

Tags: c

MY CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char main()
{
    char g1,g2,g3;
    printf("Enter the grade of student 1: ");
    scanf("%c",&g1);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 2: ");
    scanf("%c",&g2);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 3: ");
    scanf("%c",&g3);
    printf("%c%c%c",g1,g2,g3);
   
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

Enter the grade of student 1: A

Enter the grade of student 2:
Enter the grade of student 3:

//I am getting a line break and couldn't enter the value of student 2 and the cursor moves to student 3!!

Comment: Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Try `scanf(" %c",&g2);` etc.

Comment: BTW `char main()` is non-conforming, please use `int main(void)`.

Comment: Tip: Think about storing multiple values of something in an array. Steer towards using loops rather than copy-pasting code.

Comment: Tip: Stop using `scanf` for everything. Use `fgets()` instead and do your own parsing. It's not hard!

Answer (score 2):

Try doing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
char main()
{
    char g1,g2,g3;
    printf("Enter the grade of student 1: ");
    scanf(" %c",&g1);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 2: ");
    scanf(" %c",&g2);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 3: ");
    scanf(" %c",&g3);
    printf("%c%c%c",g1,g2,g3);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer here! Might I suggest that you add some details about what you fixed or why it is right? It helps users understand what is going on, rather than just being served the answer. Just a suggestion!

Comment: to reinforce @Aman remark, an answer must not be just code, this is not a suggestion but a rule, edit your answer and explain the space before `%c` even it is already said in remarks

Comment: No dude. Still not working!!!

Comment: @Vishnuvasan what is not working ? are you sure you did what is proposed ? And please never call someone *dude* except if you want to be moderated ...

Comment: Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Comment: note you do not manage the special case of an EOF when reading the grades, *scanf* returns a value, this is not for nothing

Comment: Adding the space to the format string instructs scanf to discard any whitespace characters (any of space ' ', tab '\t', or newline '\n').

Answer (score 0):

Just give a space before `%c` in `scanf` to get desired input. The below is your own code where I've added space in the second and third `scanf` statements.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
char main()
{
    char g1,g2,g3;
    printf("Enter the grade of student 1: ");
    scanf("%c",&g1);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 2: ");
    scanf(" %c",&g2);
    printf("\nEnter the grade of student 3: ");
    scanf(" %c",&g3);
    printf("%c%c%c",g1,g2,g3);
   
    return 0;
}
```

And well, the reason? If you don't, then the next `scanf` statement assumes the new line you create by pressing "Enter" as a new character, which is `\n`. So we add a space in `scanf` to let the statement know that space is not considered an input.

Comment: what appends if the user enter spaces before A (for instance) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "A"? I assume you ask what happens when user enters more than 1 space.. In that case, nothing happens. The program waits until you enter a character.

Comment: A is the first value enter in the example of the OP question . No, without a space before `%c`in the first *scanf* if the user start by space(s) you get a space for *g1*

Comment: Yeah in that case you're right. I addressed the issue @Vishnuvasan faced. Taking your case into consideration, that might also be helpful :)

Comment: the rule is simple, *never* suppose a user input is valid but *always* check it

Answer (score 0):

It is often easier to always read an entire line, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ReadLine(char result[], int resultLen)
{
    int ch, i;

    i = 0;
    ch = getchar();
    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (i < resultLen - 1) {
            result[i] = ch;
            i++;
        }
        ch = getchar();
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}


int main(void)
{
    char g1[2], g2[2] ,g3[2];
    
    printf("Enter the grade of student 1: ");
    ReadLine(g1, sizeof g1);
    printf("Enter the grade of student 2: ");
    ReadLine(g2, sizeof g2);
    printf("Enter the grade of student 3: ");
    ReadLine(g3, sizeof g3);
    printf("%s%s%s\n", g1, g2, g3);   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first Scanf will not read/flush the "\n" after reading the single char.
this character on input buffer will make the 2nd and 3rd scanf to get execute and fail without actually prompting the user.

There are multiple ways to handle this.

1. read complete line

   - use gets/fgets to rad complete inputline
   - then use scanf to read from buffer

     eg:

     fgets(buff, 255, stdin);

     sscanf(buff, "%c", &value);
2. execute a char read after every scanf statement.

   - getch()
3. Put a preceeding " " in front of every "%c" used in scanf.

   - this will skip the special char.
   - "scanf(" %c", &value);"